# Facebook webpage HTML code Update frequency

Tags: html, facebook

I have recently become aware of a major change in the HTML of the Facebook web version. Is there anywhere I can find out how often the HTML code is updated?

I've tried to ask on the Meta Developer Community Forum, but I can't post it due to 'error performing query'

Many thanks!

Comment: It changes several times a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every company has a set update frequency for their pages, and sometimes only small portions will be changed when they do update. In order to avoid and discourage scrapers, most companies won't publicly reveal it, either.

I suppose you could do your own testing and find out, but you might get a lot further by posting a question asking more specifically about what it is that you're trying to achieve